# why my adapter can't refresh it's view

Tags: android, adapter

below is my adapter code and logs (log tag is "jieke"), the problem is some times it can't display whole items in list, like only display 8 items meanwhile list size is 10!
see in the log: getCount returns 10, getView also called 10 times, but I still only seen 8 views, why?

```
public class NumberAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ArrayList<NumberModel> mPhoneNumberList;

    public NumberAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<NumberModel> phoneNumberList){
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        mPhoneNumberList = phoneNumberList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (mPhoneNumberList != null) {
            LogUtils.d("jieke", "count="+mPhoneNumberList.size() );
            return mPhoneNumberList.size();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        if (position > -1 && mPhoneNumberList != null && position < mPhoneNumberList.size()) {
            return mPhoneNumberList.get(position);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumberList(ArrayList<NumberModel> phoneNumberList){
        mPhoneNumberList = phoneNumberList;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LogUtils.d("jieke", "get view on position= " +position );
        ItemViewTag viewTag;
        if (convertView == null)  {  
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item_custom_number, null);
            viewTag = new ItemViewTag((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_image)
                ,(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_phone)
                , (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_text));  
            convertView.setTag(viewTag);  
        } else {  
            viewTag = (ItemViewTag) convertView.getTag();  
        }
        return convertView;  
    }

    class ItemViewTag { 
        protected ImageView mIcon;  
        protected ImageView mPhone;
        protected TextView mName;
        public ItemViewTag(ImageView icon, ImageView phone, TextView name){  
            this.mName = name;  
            this.mIcon = icon;  
            this.mPhone = phone;  
    }  
}
```

}

Here is Log:

```
05-13 21:20:24.975 D/absec.:CustomServiceNumberTabItemView(18651):  reset adaptor this=1
05-13 21:20:24.975 D/absec.:jieke(18651): count=10
05-13 21:20:24.975 D/absec.:jieke(18651): count=10
05-13 21:20:24.975 D/absec.:CustomServiceNumberTabItemView(18651):  notify change this=1
05-13 21:20:24.975 D/absec.:jieke(18651): count=10
05-13 21:20:24.975 D/absec.:jieke(18651): count=10
05-13 21:20:24.975 I/absec.:QBaseTabView(18651): onResume
05-13 21:20:24.985 D/absec.:jieke(18651): count=10
05-13 21:20:24.985 D/absec.:jieke(18651): get view on position= 0
05-13 21:20:24.985 D/absec.:jieke(18651): count=10
05-13 21:20:24.985 D/absec.:jieke(18651): get view on position= 0
05-13 21:20:24.985 D/absec.:jieke(18651): count=10
05-13 21:20:24.985 D/absec.:jieke(18651): get view on position= 0
05-13 21:20:24.985 D/absec.:jieke(18651): count=10
05-13 21:20:24.985 D/absec.:jieke(18651): get view on position= 0
05-13 21:20:25.005 D/absec.:jieke(18651): get view on position= 0
05-13 21:20:25.015 D/absec.:jieke(18651): get view on position= 1
05-13 21:20:25.015 D/absec.:jieke(18651): get view on position= 2
05-13 21:20:25.015 D/absec.:jieke(18651): get view on position= 3
05-13 21:20:25.015 D/absec.:jieke(18651): get view on position= 4
05-13 21:20:25.035 D/absec.:jieke(18651): get view on position= 5
05-13 21:20:25.035 D/absec.:jieke(18651): get view on position= 6
05-13 21:20:25.035 D/absec.:CustomServiceActivity(18651):  values=is_common=1
05-13 21:20:25.045 D/absec.:jieke(18651): get view on position= 7
05-13 21:20:25.045 D/absec.:CustomServiceActivity(18651):  values=is_common=1
05-13 21:20:25.055 D/absec.:jieke(18651): get view on position= 8
05-13 21:20:25.055 D/absec.:jieke(18651): get view on position= 9
05-13 21:20:25.065 D/absec.:CustomServiceActivity(18651):  values=is_common=1
05-13 21:20:25.075 D/absec.:CustomServiceActivity(18651):  values=is_common=1
05-13 21:20:25.085 D/absec.:CustomServiceActivity(18651):  values=is_common=1
05-13 21:20:25.095 D/absec.:CustomServiceActivity(18651):  values=is_common=1
05-13 21:20:25.105 D/absec.:CustomServiceActivity(18651):  values=is_common=1
05-13 21:20:25.115 D/absec.:CustomServiceActivity(18651):  values=is_common=1
05-13 21:20:25.125 D/absec.:CustomServiceActivity(18651):  values=is_common=1
05-13 21:20:25.135 D/absec.:CustomServiceActivity(18651):  values=is_common=1
05-13 21:20:25.265 D/absec.:CustomServiceNumberAddActivity(18651): AddActivity destroy
```

actually, I just need refresh gridView after mPhoneNumberList changed (after some mPhoneNumberList.add() or mPhoneNumberList.remove()) but I found using NumberAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() does not work, so every time I create a new  Adapter and reset GridView using GridView.setAdapter(newNumberAdapter), it works , but sometimes problem happened.

> problem solved, after GridView.setAdapter(newNumberAdapter)
>   add this GridView.invalidateViews() works for me!

Comment: Where you set item data ?

Comment: in Constructer method

Comment: I think you are using listview. getCount() from adapter does not return visible item count. It returns item count that contain in listview.

Comment: Can you add the code that interacts with this adapter? i.e. the setup, the binding to the AdapterView and any updates you do to this adapter. As getView(9) is being called, it suggests the ListView knows about the items, but then what is the behaviour on screen? Is the ListView scrollable, or do 8 items fit onscreen?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are using an **Asynctask**.Intialise the arraylist `ArrayList<NumberModel> mPhoneNumberList`(which you are sending as an argument in the constructor of the adapter) in the **doInBackground(String... params)** of the asynctask like: `mPhoneNumberList=new ArrayList<NumberModel>` **instead of creating the instance in onCreate().**

Try the solution.I believe your adapter will be refreshed.

Comment: not in Asynctask, gridView's adapter is created in instantiateItem() method in  PagerAdapter

Comment: just create the instance of the arraylist before calling setadapter

Answer (score 0):

problem solved, after GridView.setAdapter(newNumberAdapter)
add this GridView.invalidateViews() works for me!